# JWT token IdentityServer

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

Could someone helps me with integration jwt token into web.api core. So i tried to generate jwt token by means of IdentityServer 4. Given below is how it looks like:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginViewModel.Email);

        if(user != null)
        {
            var isCredosValid = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginViewModel.Email, loginViewModel.Password, loginViewModel.RememberMe, false);

            if (isCredosValid.Succeeded)
            {
                var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44351");
                var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, _identityServerConfig.ClientId, _identityServerConfig.Secret);

                var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(
                    loginViewModel.Email, loginViewModel.Password,_identityServerConfig.AllowedScope);

                return Json(tokenResponse.Json);
            }
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

This method gives me a token in no problem, but once i try to access the other method with role restriction like Authorize(Roles="User") Api allows me to call method without authorization, so it dosn't seem working.
Should i somehow to verify token that sends in request header manually and default asp.net user identity have buil-in support for checking tokens?

Comment: Apart from your question, it seems like the users password is in two places, once locally, once in IdentityServer, what's the reason for that? Why aren't you using the OpenIdConnect middleware to get the user redirected to the identityserver instead of this home-brew mechanism?

Comment: The point of using an external identity provider (IdP) like IdentityServer is that your application does not have to deal with user passwords, the user directly authenticates with the IdP and you application trusts the token it receives from the IdP.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Get it. Thanks. But what about verification token when user try to use token for actions with role restrictions. As far i understand the basic asp.net identity doesn't support automatic decryption of token and i need to define custom one ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'verification token', but depending on your application, with the OpenIdConnect middleware, once the token from the IdP is received, you could create your own JWT token or Cookie with any claim you want in it. This can be done by handling the [`SecurityTokenValidated notification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/mt180993%28v%3dvs.113%29) and transform the ClaimsIdentity. If you have role claims in the JWT coming from the IdP, than this handler is also a good place to debug the claims you're getting...

Comment: Can you see the role User in your JWT? We certainly can't see anything based upon what you've provided. Maybe take a look at something like [this link](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/using-roles-with-the-jwt-middleware/). It provides a pretty concise example as well as introduces nice ways to inspect and verify your token using sites like jwt.io.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit For example i gain a token. Suppose i have action method with allowed access oly for users. And i want some kind of auth attribute which will check token for validity and grant access user for this method). How i can do it?

Comment: Given the info, I think [this thread](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1786) might actually solve your issue.